# iTerm2: Selecting last-active window

Tags: macos, iterm2

Is there a way to toggle between the current and last-used window in iTerm2? I know there's "Select next window" and "Select previous window", but if I have 10 windows, I would only like to toggle between the two most recently-used windows.

Something like this: https://gyazo.com/c3aef60a99a4db33efe54ddba72ee490.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can jump between windows with ⌘ + Option + Number where number is asigned to a window in the orderd you opened it and starts on 1

What i usually do is use tabs instead of windows, and give each tab a color based on what I have on that tab for example green for compiling, red for running servers, purple for ssh connections, yellow to edit files, orange to run commands, etc, and I split each tab in four, so instead of having 8 windows to compile all the parts of the project I'm working on, I use only two tabs, this may be usefull for you if you give it a try

Comment: @pterubear -- right, but then I need to know/remember the window numbers. For example, let's say it's window 7 and 19. ?

Comment: yes, you would have to remember the window number and it will only work with 1 - 9

Comment: ah, ok. They should add that feature in, it's very helpful when working with multiple windows! (like the command-tab in Mac to view the last application)

Comment: what i usually do is use tabs instead of windows, and give each tab a color based on what I have on that tab for example green for compiling, red for running servers, purple for ssh connections, yellow to edit files, orange to run commands, etc, and I split each tab in four, so instead of having 8 windows to compile all the parts of the project I'm working on, I use only two tabs, this may be usefull for you if you give it a try

Comment: that's a great idea. thanks for the tip. Want to add that into your answer and I'll go ahead and accept it?

Comment: sure, I hope it helps